# Campo para numerar ou ranquear registros distintos - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte:

Sabendo que um atendimento pode ter vários exames, preciso numerar os exames por ordem, a fim de saber o primeiro, segundo, terceiro..., para cada atendimento.
Exemplo:

```
LINHA  ATENDIMENTO  SEQ_EXAME     
1      100          11        
2      100          13
3      100          17
1      200          83   
2      200          92
```

Utilizando o `ROWNUM` não funciona, pois ele não numera para cada atendimento diferente.

```
LINHA  ATENDIMENTO  SEQ_EXAME     
1      100          11        
2      100          13
3      100          17
4      200          83   
5      200          92
```

Poderiam me ajudar sugerindo algumas soluções?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer esta numeração agrupada, é possível utilizar a [função analítica](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407) [row_number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm), esta permite fazer agrupamentos e ordenações de registros específicos, exemplo:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Atendimento order BY seq_exame) sequencia,
       t.*
  from SUA_TABELA t
```

Comment: Opa, deu certo garoto! era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!